# get ajax xml url contain json content , how to read it by javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml, html-framework-7

```
   <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  "Result": "Sucess",
  "MotorList": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "titleen": "Camry",
      "titlear": "Multi_service"}]
</string>
```

this XML contain json , so how to parse json data from xml using javascript

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you result from ajax is not a complete JSON Object.

JSON Object starts with a

> {

and ends with

> }

Eg:

```
{
     "Result": "Sucess",
     "MotorList": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "titleen": "Camry",
          "titlear": "Multi_service"
        }
      ]
}
```

SO you need to wrap your response within {} and use JSON.parse() to parses to object

Eg:

```
let response = '"Result": "Sucess", "MotorList": [ { "id": "1", "titleen": "Camry", "titlear": "Multi_service"}]'

let json = JSON.parse("{"+response +"}")
```

Now you can access your JSON Object like

> json.Result

Answer (score 0):

In the provided response only the "MotorList" value contains valid JSON. If you can modify the service then change the response to JSON, it would be the ideal solution. But if you cannot modify the service then you have to parse it using an XML reader and do a series of string operation to get the desired value.
For example the below code extracts the "MotorList" value into JSON:

```
var parser, xmlDoc;
//Get the value from Ajax
var text = '<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
  '"Result": "Sucess",' +
  '"MotorList": [' +
    '{' +
      '"id": "1",' +
      '"titleen": "Camry",' +
      '"titlear": "Multi_service"}]' +
'</string>';

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
var resultString = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

var resultTokens = resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf(',') + 1, resultString.length)

var resultObj = JSON.parse(resultTokens.substring(resultTokens.indexOf(':') + 1, resultTokens.length))
var motorList = resultObj[0]
```